# Debug Javascript in UWP in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, debugging, windows-10-universal

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, and am building a Universal Windows App in C# (XAML). I have added a **WebView** and thereon some HTML/JS content in it.
Is there a way to debug the JS content line by line? (Similar to using F10 / F11 for C# code)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to set the properties of the project :
right click > properties > Debug > Debugger type > Application process > Script.

If you need to debug your C# code AND your JS code, you can choose the value "Managed Only" in the project Properties. For the JS code, you can use an external solution like VorlonJS : http://vorlonjs.com/. It's easy to setup and very powerful.

Comment: "Managed Only" is debugging C# Code alone. But, "Script" does the job for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who ask same question for VS 2019, it is possible to debug a WebView app with the help of [Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj)

I think it works on VS 2015 too because it seems to use MS EDGE not depending on Visual Studio.